# Why this code works fine(Im trying to get integer part of numbers)?

Tags: javascript, bit-shift

So actually i know the solution of this problem, but i cant understand how its working.
The following function get whole part of decimal value. Who can explain me, how its works?

```js
function getDecimal(num) {
    num = num << 1;
    num = num >> 1;
    return num;
}

console.log(getDecimal(123));
```

Comment: You can use `num = num >> 0;` to get whole number part

Comment: Note that a combination of `num >> 1` and `num << 1` is effectively performing an integer division by 2 and then integer multiplication by 2, and hence 123 / 2 is 61.5 rounded to 61, and then multiplied by 2 yields 122.  Note also that if you're looking for the integer portion of the number, you can also use "|0".  Eg, `123.343 |0` will return `123`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function doesn't actually work for what you're trying to do. These examples will break it:

```js
getDecimal(123.3) // returns 122
getDecimal(123) // returns 122
```

The way bitwise operators work in javascript is that they convert the number to an integer, do some processing, then convert it back to a javascript number. Effectively, your function does the following:

1. Takes input number (123.2) and converts it to an int - 123
2. Bit shift the number by 1 bit (remove last bit) - 61
3. Bit shift the number by 1 bit the other way (add a zero to the end) - 122
4. Returns this value (122)

This is not the correct way of getting the integer part of a floating point number. Use `Math.ceil(num)` instead.

Comment: I've seen `num >> 0` used as an idiom for this. It just depends on step 1.

Comment: How about this?

function getDecimal(num) {
    num = num >> 1;
    num = num << 1;
    return num;
}

console.log(getDecimal(123));

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: I edited my question, first we have to do left shit not right